# Output logs from pyscipopt

Tags: scip

It may be a basic question, but how can I view the log of the solver after the model is optimized. I came across the option to hide the outputs by specifying model.hideOutput(). Is there an option to show the outputs (by default, I don't see any output log. I am using Spyder IDE).

Answer (score 0):

Printing the SCIP output is activated by default in PySCIPOpt. As you already wrote, you would have to manually disable it by calling `hideOutput()`. Have you tried running your code in a terminal outside of Spyder? Is the model even solved, so did you check whether there is a solution in the end?

Comment: The model is solved to optimality and I can get the variable values, but doesn't give any output log in the terminal. I have not tried it outside the spyder terminal. I will try it outside the spyder terminal.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the other answer: if your PySCIPOpt model has been created by third-party code, it is possible the output has been turned off upstream.

You can still call `model.hideOutput(False)` -- see the documentation of [hideOutput()](https://scipopt.github.io/PySCIPOpt/docs/html/classpyscipopt_1_1scip_1_1Model.html#a03f0fce05d206ac17a0404b00a7fd310).